# Email conversion tracking integration

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, conversion, email-tracking, tracking

I want to track conversion informations for emails.
I have found these resources:

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_es_conversion_tracking.htm&type=5

It seems that it can be implemented using a pixel.
Do you now if it is possible to use this feature without using the pixel to directly make the request?
From our infrastructure point of view, it would be perfect a solution that implements the following flow:

Client -> REST api call to our backend -> Backend -> REST api call to MarketingCloud (for example using the same url that I should insert inside the pixel ).

Has anyone ever tried to do so, or does know if it is possible?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Tracking pixel is essentially a simple way to do an HTTP GET request. There is [an example here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_es_php_conv_samples.htm&type=5), outlining how to build the solution utilising PHP/JS. You can adapt it to perform in backend mode by callling the http://click.exacttarget.com/conversion.aspx URL from your server side code, appending the relevant information in the XML payload.

You need to observe, that you still need to manage the relationship between the browser, and these variables:

```
$JobID = $_COOKIE['JobID']; 
$SubscriberID = $_COOKIE['SubscriberID']; 
$ListID = $_COOKIE['ListID']; 
$BatchID = $_COOKIE['BatchID']; 
$UrlID = $_COOKIE['UrlID']; 
$MemberID = $_COOKIE['MemberID'];
```

You can use it as described in the documentation, and set the standard conversion tracking cookie, or store it differently (in session variables, or local storage). You just need to be able to access these variables on the conversion page, and append it to the XML payload sent as a GET request to the pixel URL.